# How to make row to auto resize

Tags: c#, datagrid, cells

I want to make my row to auto resize depending on screen size.
When I do this for column it really works:

```
grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

But when I want to do same thing for row. I don't have fill option.
I only have like

```
grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

How can I make my rows to fill my screen depending on it's size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`AutoResizeRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158600.aspx) method.

Per MSDN:

> This method is useful if you want to control when a row resizes. The row height is adjusted only once per method call; if the contents of the row later change, the row will not automatically adjust. To resize all rows, use the AutoResizeRows method. To set the row to automatically resize whenever its contents change, use the AutoSizeRowsMode property.

There's also a MSDN sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff173xd4.aspx).

You may want to look in to the `RowTemplate` property named `Height`.  You can do your calculation as to when the screen size changes

EDIT:

You can put this in a resizing event, such as `Form_ResizeEnd`.  YMMV on how the grid may perform with a large number of rows.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Height = 22; //your calculation based on the screen height
}
```

I believe you can use `System.Windows.Form.Screens` class, specifically `Screens.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height` if you want the primary screen's height.  It's up to you to see what kind of size you want to maintain.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. But how can I compose this to use fill mode? So it can fill my screen?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your English.  Perhaps you can post a screenshot of what you want to do?

Comment: I am sorry about my English but I am writing in a big hurry. So I start my form in a full screen mode. And my datagrid is resized to fit the form. When I start drawing my datagrid, my width is filled with the columns which fit perfectly to my screen ( when I click on my last column on the right I can't go more than my screen size is ), problem is with my rows, when I start it and when I click on my last row which I see on my screen I can still go down with my arrow key. And I don't want to do that. I just want it to fit as my columns do.

Comment: @denonth: That's because there is more data (obviously) than the grid can display on the screen!  You will have to calculate what you want your row height to be, say 22.  Then, your code will have to figure out how many can be displayed (22 * number of records being < screen height). In the future, you might want to be just as specific in your questions as you are in your comments... even show pictures if your English skills are lacking.